# Proper way to sync Google Cal to iCal

Tags: ical, google

I have a google calendar and I need to have several iCal sync and pull updates from this Google Calendar. However, I went in and used prefs->add account to setup sync. I was told this was not the correct way to pull calendar data and that I should use the SUBSCRIBE option.

I vaguely remember going in and using the subscribe option to subscribe to the calendar but I never got updates even with a refresh. Did I do something wrong or do updates take time to get updated on googles side?

Really confused as to the differences between the two and the best way to constantly pull updates from the Google Cal to iCal.

Answer (score 1):

> I was told this was not the correct way to do.

But does it work?

Generally it sounds like what you did was correct, but just to be sure:

1. Open System Preferences and select the "Mail, Contacts & Calendar" preference (soon to be more sensible titled "Internet Accounts"
2. Click the "+" button to add an account.
3. Select "Gmail" as that account type.
4. Enter the Credentials for your Google Calendar.
5. Profit.